# AspectJ in Eclipse - project clean after change

Tags: java, eclipse, aspectj, aspect

I have quite annoying problem with Eclipse and AspectJ. After each change in class that is under effect of aspect I need to do a full project rebuild (clean).
Anyone have an idea how can I avoid that?

```
package pl.xxx.infrastructure.jdbc;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.DeclareParents;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

import pl.xxx.infrastructure.jdbc.common.UpdateEntityInterface;

@Aspect
public class UpdateEntityAspect {

    /**
     * Wyszukiwanie wszystkich klas z adnotacją Entity
     */
    @Pointcut("within(@javax.persistence.Entity pl.xxx..*)")
    public void beanAnnotatedWithEntity() {
    }

    /**
     * Wyszukiwanie wszystkich metod z nazwą rozpoczynającą się od set
     */
    @Pointcut("execution(public * set*(..))")
    public void setMethod() {
    }

    /**
     * Wyszukiwanie wszystkich pol w momencie zmodyfikacji ich stanu
     */
    @Pointcut("set(private * *)")
    public void privateField() {
    }

    /**
     * Nadawanie encji dodatkowego interfejsu / wstrzykiwanie dodatkowych pol
     */
    @DeclareParents(value = "@javax.persistence.Entity pl.xxx..*", defaultImpl = UpdateEntityInterface.UpdateEntityInterfaceImpl.class)
    UpdateEntityInterface updateEntityInterface;

    /**
     * Kod wstrzykiwany podczas modyfikowania pola encji
     * 
     * @param joinPoint
     * @param entity
     */
    @Before("beanAnnotatedWithEntity() && privateField() && target(entity)")
    public void onSetExecuted(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object entity) {
        if (entity instanceof UpdateEntityInterface) {
            UpdateEntityInterface updateEntityInterface = (UpdateEntityInterface) entity;
            updateEntityInterface._markUpdated(joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
        }
    }

}
```

Class under Aspect infuence:

```
package pl.xxx.model.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

@Entity
@Table(name="CUSTOMER")
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9128787620983157104L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="IdGenerator", sequenceName="SEQ_CUSTOMER", allocationSize=1)
    @Column(name="ID", unique=true, nullable=false, precision=15, scale=0)  
    protected Long id;

    @Column(name="FILE_TYPE", length=3)
    @CorelatedEnum(IncomingFileType.class)
    private String fileType;
}
```

Error: The type Customer must implement the inherited abstract method UpdateEntityInterface._getUpdatedFields() Customer.java   line 17 Java Problem

Comment: That sounds like an AspectJ bug, the incremental compiler is not making the right decision. Have you tried using `@DeclareMixin` rather than `@DeclareParents` - it should achieve a similar thing but I just wonder if incremental compilation better handles the mixin case.  New AspectJ bugs go here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=AspectJ

Comment: It's working with @DeclareMixin! Thank you man. You saved me a lot of rebuilds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use Andy Clement solution - DeclareMixin instead of DeclareParents
2. Try to put your aspect classes into other lib (project) as default spring aspects. If you hava maven project you can add them as follows

   ```
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
           <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <configuration>
               <aspectLibraries>
                   <aspectLibrary>
                       <groupId>...</groupId>
                       <artifactId>...</artifactId>
                   </aspectLibrary>
               </aspectLibraries>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
   ```